# Theoretical upper bounds of classification accuracy?

Tags: classification, bounds

I'm looking for theoretical upper bounds of classification accuracy. Please let me know if you are familiar with results like the following. **The setup below is a general one, but please share results you know that apply in particular settings as well. Thanks!**

Let $Y$ be the binary variable to classify and $X = (X_1,...,X_K)$ be $K$ explanatory variables. We know the joint distribution (in population) of $(y,X) \sim \mu$ and want to build a model of $\hat{y} = f(X)$. Then for the class of XXX functions $f()$, there will be an upper bound to the maximum classification accuracy: $P(\hat{y} = y) \le g(\mu(y,X))$?

Comment: Thanks @nick. I'm new to stackexchange and am still learning how to format questions appropriately.

Comment: Let the marginal distribution of $X$ be $F_X$. If for each $x$ you predict $Y=1$ when $p(x)=\Pr(Y=1|X=x)\gt 1/2$ and otherwise predict $Y=0$, the expected accuracy is $\int\max(p(x),1-p(x))dF_X(x)$. It's easy to show this is a universal upper bound. Is this the kind of result you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Apologize in advance for a less-than-definitive answer, but hopefully this answer will be helpful.

In the totally general case, (i.e. arbitrary Y,X) I would conjecture that no such bound exists, except for the trivial answer of perfect classification.

The reason I make this conjecture is the similar issues addressed by the [no free lunch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization) .

I think your question is more likely to be about a specific instance (i.e. with a specific, known data set)

In this case, I can suggest an approach... although this approach may or may not be useful in practice.

I am assuming that the values of X are all finite and discrete, or can be made so without loss of discrimination power.

Consider the set of all your observations, partitioned into a grid consisting of X(k,l) where l is the levels of each variable Xk.

Take the sum of the minority values of y (the binary value you are predicting) in each cell, and divide by n.

Since, in a given cell the best possible prediction is the ratio of majority/minority observations in that cell.  No better prediction is possible for that cell, because, by construction, the cell comprises of a unique combinations of X values.   No additional information is available from X to discriminate further.

Comment: Thanks for the response @JBK. I'm not quite sure I understand: you are thinking of the case when $X$ has finite resolution, therefore the accuracy will be fundamentally limited by the coarseness of that resolution?

Comment: @J Li, yes, although it is the coarseness of the resolution with respect to the values of Y, not just the general coarseness.  The finite case (where all X are categorical) is one scenario.  In most real world scenarios arbitrary resolution of X is unreasonable... e.g.  If  x1 = 1.00031 => y1 = 0   x2 = 1.000309 => y1 = 1 x3 = 1.000311 =>  y2 = 0 etc.  Another way to say this is that in most cases, "reasonable" discretization should be possible without introducing a large loss of information.

Comment: May I interpret your suggestion, @JBK, in measure theory language as follows? Say a predictor random variable X is measurable w.r.t. sigma-field F_X, then any function f(X) will be measurable w.r.t (at most) F_X. Therefore the optimal predictor of Y is the conditional expectation F(Y|F_X), and therefore the total variation of Y - E(Y|F_X) is the minimum classification error.